# mysql date goes 1 day earlier

Tags: php, mysql

Hey I am having trouble with dates currently. I have a simple table like this.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pages` (
`page_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`day_of_birth` date NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`page_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

I insert string to the database  (YYYY-MM-DD)

```
'1980-06-05'
```

and I echo the date like this:

```
echo date('d.m.Y',strtotime($page_info['day_of_birth']));
```

My problem is every day date record goes 1 day earlier. 
For instance, I save this date '1980-06-05'. next day I will see '1980-06-04' in my database and the day after that it will be '1980-06-03'. I think the type of the column cause that. What do you think? How can I fix this problem? is my echoing code correct?

Comment: What is the timezone set to in php.ini? Try a date in the winter months and see if it does the same thing.

Comment: no the database column and data type looks good, and mysql does not change the dates by its own, check if the selection is selecting properly.

Comment: Strtotime gets the unix timestamp of a date, which will be taken from midnight if you only have year-month-day. So when a summer time date is stored it'll lose an hour, falling into the previous day. This assumes your timezone observes daylight savings.

Comment: set your specific time zone  like for India **date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");**

Comment: related: [how to set mysql timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-do-i-set-the-time-zone-of-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

I was using this code from github https://github.com/abecoffman 
and I noticed that it has really specific problem with google chrome. You can see the issue here:
https://github.com/abecoffman/birthdaypicker/issues/20 and here: https://github.com/abecoffman/birthdaypicker/pull/8 well it still does not work for me but I will try to fix it later. This question is not a database question anymore. Thank you for your answers.